# OracleXE install the SCOTT schema on Windows

Tags: oracle, installation, demo

I want to create the SCOTT demo schema on OracleXE 18.c
I managed to install the HR demo following the instructions from the Oracle documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00005
and I have also located the scott.sql file which resides under this directory "C:\OracleDatabaseXE\dbhomeXE\rdbms\admin\scott.sql"
however I cannot successfully install it and view the tables created, any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us an error message?

Comment: the HR schema resides under this directory:
SQL> @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql
however the scott.sql file resides in another directory and when typing
@?/rdbms/admin/scott.sql in SQL Plus
I get no results, just a new blank SQL> line

Comment: Does this work? `@?/rdbms/admin/utlsampl.sql`

Comment: this closes the SQL Plus command window entirely, when I ran the 
@?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql
I got the following prompt:
"specify password for HR as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: "
 which led to the further creation of the schema upon entering the credentials

Comment: Closing the window is expected behaviour becasue the script ends with a command `EXIT;`. If you didn't get an error message, I guess everything went fine. Just check if the schema `SCOTT` is there, password is - as everybody knows - `tiger`

Answer (score 0):

Please connect to the database and check if there is a user `SCOTT`, for instance with

```
SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE username='SCOTT';
```

If yes, then everything is fine. If not, you can also login to SQL Developer (or a similar tool) and execute the statements yourself. The file is for instance [here](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/schemas/scott.sql).

Comment: ORA-01918 user 'SCOTT' does not exist

Comment: Did you run the statements in the file on github?

Comment: these are just a partial of the full scott schema. For example table student is missing entirely

Comment: No, just compared the github file with `utlsampl.sql` from Oracle 18.3 (Linux), and the tables are identical. Haven't heard of a student table.